# Calculate area between $f$ and $f^{-1}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Consider $f:[0, 1] \to [0, 1], \: f(x) = x e^{x^2 - 1}$.

Calculate $$I=\int_0^1 |f(x) - f^{-1}(x)|dx$$

I know $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$.

If I had to calculate $$\int_0^1 f^{-1}(x)dx$$ I would put $x = f(y)$ but I don't know how to deal with $I$ because of the absolute value.

Comment: You have first to check that $f$ is a monotonic function on [0,1]. Otherwise $f^{-1}$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x) = xe^{x^2-1}$, so 
$$ f'(x) = e^{x^2-1} + 2x^2 e^{x^2-1} = e^{x^2-1}(1+2x^2)$$
and
$$ f''(x) = 2xe^{x^2-1}(1+2x^2) + e^{x^2-1}(4x) = e^{x^2-1}(4x^3 + 6x). $$

Note that $f'(x) > 0$ on $(0,1)$.  Therefore $f(x) = xe^{x^2-1}$ is strictly increasing on $(0,1)$.  Therefore $f^{-1}$ actually exists, at least on $[0,1]$, which is all we care about here.

Also, $f''(x) > 0$ on $(0,1)$.  Therefore $f(x)$ is strictly convex (sometimes also called "strictly concave up" or just "concave up" depending on who you talk to) on $(0,1)$.

$f(0) = 0$, $f(1) = 1$, and $f(x)$ is strictly convex on $(0,1)$.  Therefore the graph of $y=f(x)$ on $[0,1]$ lies entirely below the segment of the line $y=x$ from $x=0$ to $x=1$, except *at* $x=0$ and $x=1$, which is where the graphs coincide.

Therefore... I'll leave the rest to you, but what does this tell you about the graph of $y=f^{-1}(x)$, and therefore the relationship between $f(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$, on the interval $[0,1]$?

Comment: Therefore. $\quad$

Comment: I used that $f^{-1}$ and $f$ are symmetrical towards $y = x$ so it's done. Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

Put $x=f(y)$.

$$\int_0^1f^{-1}(x)dx=\int_0^1yf'(y)dy=\left[yf(y)\right]_0^1-\int_0^1f(y)dy=1-\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

Note that for $x\in[0,1]$,

$$e^{x^2-1}\le 1$$

$$f(x)\le x$$

Therefore $f^{-1}(x)\ge x\ge f(x)$ and hence $|f(x)-f^{-1}(x)|=f^{-1}(x)-f(x)$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand your first equality.

Comment: @JeanMarie If $x=f(y)$, then $f^{-1}(x)=y$ and $\frac{dx}{dy}=f'(y)dy$. That's why the integrand is $yf'(y)$. Since $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$, both the lower limit and the upper limit remains unchanged after the substitution.

Comment: CY Kwong Thanks for these explanations. I think they will be helpful for the OP as well.

Comment: Thank you, but I said I know how to solve that integral, all I don't know is how to deal with the absolute value(like, where is $f > f^{-1}$ or $f < f^{-1}$).